# Are google's AdMob advertisements free to show in your android app?

Tags: android, admob

I've been trying to show ads in my Android app. I've used TapIt and SOMA(www.smaato.com) library for that but im having issues with both of them as TapIt is not free to use and SOMA is using an Async Task to update its adds whereas i want ads to run on a thread. I'm trying to do this with AdMob now, I've created an account, it gives me two options:

```
1) Start a campaign
2) Add a site/app
```

In both the cases i've to pay. Is there a way where i can have my ads on my app for which i don't have to pay. Something like a trial version for developers or kindly suggest any other library that I can use.
Thank You in advance.

PS: My app isn't on Google play

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pricing and/or legal stuff rather than any programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Google's admob advertisement are free to show in your app -

go through AdMob docs -
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

login Google AdMob site.
after login check for  - > Sites & Apps

- > Add site/App fill the all details.
- > use the publisher ID in your code

for this you don't have to pay anything.
then you've ads on your Android Application.

You can also participate in the [GOOGLE ADMOB](https://www.google.com/admob/challenge.html) competition. Where the Grand Prize winner will score a week-long trip to San Francisco, including a visit to Google’s headquarters in Mountain View

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response Umesh. In the details it asks for adding Local Tax ID and Payment details. So I'll get my publisher ID only after i fill these details??

Comment: yes u've to add ID and Payment Details.